# rangeSpecification --> Trouble to call in a script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, colors, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm trying to build a script to count how many cells with some backgroundcolor i have in a line.
This is what i have:

```
function PegarCorFundo(rangeSpecification) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  return sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification).getBackgroundColor();
}

function ContarCorFundo(color, rangeSpecification) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification);
  var x = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= range.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= range.getNumColumns(); j++) {
      var cell = range.getCell(i, j);
      if(cell.getBackgroundColor() == color)
        x++;
    }
  }
  return x;
}
```

The problem is when i call de function in Google Sheets. When i call
=ContarCorFundo("#ffff99";A1:A22), a error message appears.

When i call =ContarCorFundo("#ffff99";"A1:A22"), is ok!

Segue o link da Planilha em uso: https://docs.google.com/a/crescercampinas.com.br/spreadsheets/d/1jkoIEwNCRU7uX7dTZK9ZLCR_zOO3q4fI_ulzhKSs_yA/edit?usp=sharing

How can i call the funcion Without quotation marks or a a better way to count the cells with backgroud color?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use quotation marks, you are not passing the range but the values of that range to the function. The .getBackground() method requires a range-object. So you'll have to make sure a range is passed to the function. Note that there is also an add-on called [Custom Count and Sum](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-count-and-sum/njiklelndjpdbdngfkdgeijcpfabfgkb) that has this functionality built in.